# How to rewrite on several terminal lines in Python

Tags: python-3.x, terminal

I'm trying to rewrite on two lines on my terminal from a Python3 script.
Let's take a quick example:

```py
import time

for n in range(1, 10):
    print(n)
    print(n*2)
    time.sleep(1)
```

When i launch my script I'd like to have this output :

```sh
bla@bla:/tmp$ python3 test.py
1
2
```

Then a second later (after the sleep) I want the 2 numbers to be "replaced by the new output" like this :

```sh
bla@bla:/tmp$ python3 test.py
2
4
```

and so on...

**What have I tested ?**

- I've tried to put `os.system("clear")` at the begining of my for loop, but it's pretty uggly and it doesn't do what I want...
- I've tried to put `end '\r'` at the end of my print as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8436827/15408692)
- I've tried to launch [this commands](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16745408/15408692) with `os.system()` but it didn't work

**Do you have any solutions ? Thanks for your help.**

Comment: @mkrieger1it works too but the solution of Thickycat is pretty easier. Thanks for your answer, I learnt some new stuff though!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'll depend on the terminal emulator you use, but you probably want the ANSI 'cursor up' codes to be output, which will move the cursor up ready for the next iteration.  The code you want is "ESCAPE [ A"

```
import time

for n in range(1, 10):
    print(n)
    print(n*2)
    time.sleep(1)
    print("\033[A\033[A", end="")
```

An ESCAPE is character 27, which is 033 in octal.
Note the end="" to stop the cursor moving down again...